# performance improvement - how to get started

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, jboss, httpclient

I have an application that runs on jboss 5, uses struts2 ,JAXB, Apache HTTP client to contact other servers in business logic, oracle db for some select operations and insertion of logs.There is a heavy use of concurrent hashmap for session management,there is lot of static data being cached in servletcontext too .the TPS that i get now is around 150 TPS and the requirement is to get 3000 TPS,

1. is this realistic?
2. what are the things i can start looking at?

using java 5 now

Thanks for any pointers and help

Comment: Every optimization starts with profiling to diagnose the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

1. You must use JProfiler, yourkit, or any other profiling tool to understand where are your bottlenecks at code level.

Some thoughts about possible places to look:

XML and Serialization: 
1. I saw some performance issues with JAXB. 
 Is XML a necessity? most JSON serializers I know are better than JAXB when it comes to performance. 
2. In addition, think if you need to serialize all the data, and not have some of it transient (also something I encountered). 
3. Working with XML Documents (DOM) has its performance toll. 
DB: 
1. Use explain to analyze your oracle DB queries (I hope this is how it called at oracle - it will show you the execution plan of and will explain you it so you can find how to improve). 
2. Consider using stored procedures - they are compiled on the Oracle server and have better performance (comparing with generated queries). 
3. Use proper indexing on the DB. 
4. In some  cases, consider even data duplication (yes, it's ugly, I know) if it will eliminate you some of the joins. 
5. Understand issues like IN vs EXISTS and which one should be used. 
Data access layer: 
1. Try to see if you can use some entities cache (i.e - 1st level or 2nd level cache of hibernate, or your own implementation) to avoid redundant queries to DB. 
6. Concurrency - 
You did not provide enough information. 
1. You should consider using for example ReaderWriterLock and not "synchronized" where possible. 
2. Try to synchronize areas of code that are short as possible.
3. Move toJDK 6! I heard that they improved performance on synchronized there.
7. Transactions: 
1. Remember transactions are expensive resources, make sure not to open them for "read only" flows of code. 
2. Make sure to have transactions short as possible. 
I can go on and on and on, but you really must explain more about your results + system so we can really direct you.

Comment: @ zaske : You made a bad question useful with your generally useful answer :) +

Comment: @Jayan - thanks for the compliment. It is important for me to answer these questions, because I know performance tuning is hard (its even very hard for me) -so I want to give people directions on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i shall keep you posted on the steps i took and the profiling results. xml parsing cant be avoided as the external aplication this interacts with sends xml response.Your response was very informative.